# How to join tables with OR condition in data.table

Tags: r, join, merge, data.table

Is this possible in data.table to join tables with OR condition?

For example:

```
library(data.table)
X<-data.table(x=c('a','b','c','d','e','f'),y=c(1,1,2,2,3,3),z=c(10,11,12,13,14,15))
   x y  z
1: a 1 12
2: b 1 11
3: c 2 12
4: d 2 13
5: e 3 14
6: f 3 15  

Y<-data.table(x=c('a','e','a'),z=c(12,20,14),t=c('a','b','c'))
   x  z t
1: a 12 a
2: e 20 b
3: a 14 c

# and i need something like this:
X[Y,on=c("x"|"z"),.(x,y,z,i.t)]
   x y  z t
1: a 1 10 a
2: a 1 10 c
3: b 1 11 NA
4: c 2 12 a
5: d 2 13 NA
6: e 3 14 b
7: e 3 14 c
8: f 3 15 NA
```

I haven't found information about joining with OR in documentation.
Have I missed something?

Comment: I think you have some typo in your example

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The OP requested that the result set should consist of 3 subsets:

1. rows matching on column `x`
2. rows matching on column `y`
3. remaining rows of data.table `X`

So, this is a kind of right outer join of table `X` with `Y` on either column `x` or `y`.

This can be translated into 2 separate inner joins on column `x` and `y` resp., a union of both result sets, and a final outer join to add the remaining rows from table `X`.

Combined in one `data.table` statement this becomes

```
unique(rbindlist(list(
  X[Y, on = "x", .(x, y, z, t), nomatch = 0],
  X[Y, on = "z", .(x, y, z, t), nomatch = 0]
)))[X, on = .(x, y, z)]
#   x y  z  t
#1: a 1 10  a
#2: a 1 10  c
#3: b 1 11 NA
#4: c 2 12  a
#5: d 2 13 NA
#6: e 3 14  b
#7: e 3 14  c
#8: f 3 15 NA
```

The inner joins are enforced by parameter `nomatch = 0`. The union operation is implemented using `rbindlist(list(...))`. **EDIT:** `unique()` is required to remove double matches in case where `x` and `z` are matching in the same row in `X` and in `Y` ([thanks to filius_arator for pointing this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42788641/how-to-join-with-or-in-data-table/42817391#comment72766743_42817391)).

The final right outer join uses all rows of `X` including those which haven't been matched yet. Note that this join is on the three columns of `X`.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!

Comment: Adding `unique()` statement let us to avoid double match in case where `x` and `z` are matching in the same row in `X` and in `Y`.

Comment: @filius_arator Good point! I've updated accordingly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is what you want or if it is very data.table-esque but there's no other answers at the moment:

```
join1 <- merge(X, Y[,c('x', 't'), with=FALSE], all.x=TRUE)
merge(join1, Y[,c('z', 't'), with=FALSE], all.x=TRUE, by = 'z')[, 
    t := ifelse(!is.na(t.x), t.x, t.y)][,
    t.x := NULL][,
    t.y := NULL][]
```

Giving:

```
    z x y  t
1: 10 a 1  a
2: 11 b 1 NA
3: 12 c 2  a
4: 13 d 2 NA
5: 14 e 3  b
6: 15 f 3 NA
```

**EDIT** with the updated example here's an approach but I'm sure there are better ways that the data.table gurus could should:

```
join1 <- merge(X, Y[,c('x', 't'), with=FALSE], all.x=TRUE)
merge(join1, Y[,c('z', 't'), with=FALSE], all.x=TRUE, by = 'z')[,
    id := seq(.N)][, 
    .(t =list( na.omit(c(t.x, t.y)))), by = c('id', 'x', 'y', 'z')][,
    .(x=x, y=y, z=z, t=unlist(t)), by = c('id')][]

##    id x y  z  t
## 1:  1 a 1 10  a
## 2:  2 a 1 10  c
## 3:  3 b 1 11 NA
## 4:  4 c 2 12  a
## 5:  5 d 2 13 NA
## 6:  6 e 3 14  b
## 7:  6 e 3 14  c
## 8:  7 f 3 15 NA
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It is working like UPDATE. For this example it works good but i need JOIN. In specific condition UPDATE won't work like and need. I have updated code in my question Which Provides better example.

Comment: I'm _not_ sure if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42817391/3817004) is a better solution but it looks more concise. Would be interesting to run a benchmark with some large data.tables.