# data.table OR joins

Tags: r, join, data.table

I have been looking but except for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42788641/how-to-join-tables-with-or-condition-in-data-table) by @Uwe, I cannot find a more succinct answer

Say we have the below 2 tables:

```
library(data.table)

df <- data.table(x = 1:2
                 , y = 3:4
                 ); df
   x y
1: 1 3
2: 2 4

df_1 <- data.table(x = 2:3
                   , y = 5:6
                   ); df_1
   x y
1: 2 5
2: 3 6
```

If I wanted to get rows where `x=x or x=y` (`df_1` on left side), I tried the below but syntax is wrong:

```
df_1[df, on=.(x=x |x=y)]
```

Instead, I am having to do (again, by @Uwe, link above):

```
unique(rbindlist(list(df_1[df, on=.(x), nomatch=0]
                      , df_1[df, on=.(x=y), nomatch=0]
                      )
                 , use.names = T
                 , fill = T
                 )
       )

   x y i.y i.x
1: 2 5   4  NA
2: 3 6  NA   1
```

Which does work but is far from succinct and is not intuitive at a glance.
p.s. not a jab at @Uwe, very thankful, in fact. But wonder if we now have a more succinct method.

Comment: Some updated syntax, but essentially the same as @Uve's: `rbind(df_1[df, on = c('x == x'), nomatch = NULL], 
      df_1[df, on = c('x == y'), nomatch = NULL], 
      fill = TRUE) |> 
  unique()`

Comment: Please put what is needed to ask your question in your post, not just at a link. Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Give credit. If you augment with a link, say what it is doing there via text in your post. (Posts should be self-contained & links die.)